# TV connected to PC doesn't catch signal when PC returns from stand-by

Tags: windows-8, hdmi, dvi, tv

I have a media center PC with Windows 8 which is connected to my TV (from DVI to HDMI). When idle, the PC goes into stand-by. But when the PC comes back from stand-by, the TV doesn't get a signal anymore. I have to restart the PC to get the image back.

Before this, I had Windows 7. Here I had s similar problem, but then it only happend when the PC was returning from stand-by AFTER the TV was turned on. Then I could fix it by putting the PC back to stand-by and then back on again.

I tried to install new display drivers. No success.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is test the setup, but with a PC LCD monitor.  If it works normally, then the issue is with your TV.  TVs are not designed like LCD monitors and may not interpret the many different sleep, standby, power signals, etc that the PC puts out.  If this is the case, check your TVs manual, or call their technical support.  They may have a solution or workaround, but other than that, you may be out of luck.

Comment: But with Windows 7, it did interpret the signal when it came back from standby. Does this mean Windows 8 sends a different signal than Windows 7 when retuning from standby? Is there maybe a way to manually send these signals?

Comment: Its most likely the graphics card driver that sends the signals...  honestly, not my area of expertise.

Answer (score 0):

We only can guess there.

1. Check if system and video drivers are up to date.
2. Sometimes video driver have options for power management and reinitialization from hibernate. (sometimes hidden in registry, search for tweaks)